# Bold txtcontent text and not the sharepoint field?

Tags: json-formatting

I would like to bold a text within txtcontent. How can I bold the text "PRODUCT CHANGE TITLE"?

```
"txtcontent": "='PRODUCT CHANGE TITLE: '+[$ProductchangeTitle]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the data into two **span** elements like shown below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "font-weight": "bold"
      },
      "txtContent": "PRODUCT CHANGE TITLE"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "[$ProductchangeTitle]"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]